# Time Zone Countdown script, not working as intended?

Tags: javascript, timezone

I was on the lookout for a javascript countdown with adjustable timezones, and found this script called tzcount.js. According to the instructions:

> The month can be specified as a number between 1 and 12 to indicate
>   which month of the year that you are counting down to (**it will assume
>   next year if the month has already past for this year**)

But when I enter the value 1 for month, the script tells me that the date has passed, instead of assuming it is the first month of the next year. Am I missing something or is this script not working as intended?

The full script:

```
<!--Copy and paste just above the close </BODY> of you HTML webpage.-->

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">

// ****  Time Zone Count Down Javascript  **** //
/*
Visit http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/
 for this script and many more
*/

////////// CONFIGURE THE COUNTDOWN SCRIPT HERE //////////////////

var month = '*';     //  '*' for next month, '0' for this month or 1 through 12 for the month 
var day = '1';       //  Offset for day of month day or + day  
var hour = 0;        //  0 through 23 for the hours of the day
var tz = -5;         //  Offset for your timezone in hours from UTC
var lab = 'tzcd';    //  The id of the page entry where the timezone countdown is to show

function start() {displayTZCountDown(setTZCountDown(month,day,hour,tz),lab);}

    // **    The start function can be changed if required   **
window.onload = start;

////////// DO NOT EDIT PAST THIS LINE //////////////////

function setTZCountDown(month,day,hour,tz) 
{
var toDate = new Date();
if (month == '*')toDate.setMonth(toDate.getMonth() + 1);
else if (month > 0) 
{ 
if (month <= toDate.getMonth())toDate.setYear(toDate.getYear() + 1);
toDate.setMonth(month-1);
}
if (day.substr(0,1) == '+') 
{var day1 = parseInt(day.substr(1));
toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+day1);
} 
else{toDate.setDate(day);
}
toDate.setHours(hour);
toDate.setMinutes(0-(tz*60));
toDate.setSeconds(0);
var fromDate = new Date();
fromDate.setMinutes(fromDate.getMinutes() + fromDate.getTimezoneOffset());
var diffDate = new Date(0);
diffDate.setMilliseconds(toDate - fromDate);
return Math.floor(diffDate.valueOf()/1000);
}
function displayTZCountDown(countdown,tzcd) 
{
if (countdown < 0) document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = "Sorry, you are too late."; 
else {var secs = countdown % 60; 
if (secs < 10) secs = '0'+secs;
var countdown1 = (countdown - secs) / 60;
var mins = countdown1 % 60; 
if (mins < 10) mins = '0'+mins;
countdown1 = (countdown1 - mins) / 60;
var hours = countdown1 % 24;
var days = (countdown1 - hours) / 24;
document.getElementById(tzcd).innerHTML = days + " day" + (days == 1 ? '' : 's') + ' + ' +hours+ 'h : ' +mins+ 'm : '+secs+'s';
setTimeout('displayTZCountDown('+(countdown-1)+',\''+tzcd+'\');',999);
}
}
</SCRIPT>
<p><font face="arial" size="-2">The countdown script at </font><br><font face="arial, helvetica" size="-2"><a href="http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/">Rainbow Arch</a></font></p>
```

I found the script, and the instructions, here http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/timezone_countdown.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script isn't working right.

You need to edit this line:

```
if (month <= toDate.getMonth())toDate.setYear(toDate.getYear() + 1);
```

`getYear` abbreviates, so it returns 115 for this year. `setYear` then thinks you mean 115 AD, which passed a *long* time ago.

Replace `setYear` and `getYear` with `setFullYear` and `getFullYear`. Those functions will return/expect 2015.